# RabbitMQ basic_get with multiple consumers

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I'm moving some resource intensive functionality currently running on a cron to a RabbitMQ queue. I'm weary of having long running PHP consumer scripts so I'm thinking of doing the following:

1. Jobs are added to the queue at the start of the day.
2. A cron runs a command which starts a consumer.
3. The consumer uses `basic_get` to get a job, processes the job, acknowledges the job and then exits.
4. The cron runs again and the next job is processed.

I have a couple of questions around how well this will work.

If I decide to fire up 2 workers via the cron (running the command twice) and the first job is still being processed, and hasn't been acknowledged, would RabbitMQ ever send the same job to the second worker?

I've noticed that `basic_consume` will be more performant since there's no round trip when receiving each job. Is it possible to use `basic_consume` rather than `basic_get` without having to worry about the workers being left to run for too long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part:
No it would not. This would happen only in the case when the first consumer dies without ACKing the message-  then that message gets requeued and the next consumer gets it.

The second part:
You should use `basic_consume` because it's faster, asynchronous and generally better. Using any message retrieval methods has nothing to do with how long will the consumers run.

Comment: i agree w/ cantSleepNow for the first part and he is correct about basic_consume being more performant when you are leaving a subscriber alive and letting it handle multiple messages. i'm not sure i would suggest basic_consume in your case, though. since you want to to handle a single message and then exit the process, basic_get might be the right choice.

Comment: Thanks guys. The plan eventually is to have a Go app as a long running worker that fires off the commands whenever a job is added to the queue. The single job execution is just a stop gap while we're using PHP as the listener since I'm not convinced by the reliability of long running PHP scripts. So I guess the basic_get will do. I can still fire up multiple consumers if we have a backlog.

@DerickBailey I signed up for your RMQPatterns emails a few days ago, been very helpful so far. Thanks!